# Same color for android and iphone

Tags: android, iphone, colors

I tried to use the same color used in iphone to my android device

This is the color for iphone.

```
(UIColor *)navBarColor {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:0.329f green:0.584f blue:0.898f alpha:1.0f];
}
```

I tried to convert the above using the below lines of code to use for android

```
String colorString =
            String.format("%s%s%s%s",
            Integer.toString(Math.round((1.0f*255)), 16),  
            Integer.toString(Math.round((102.0f/255.0f*255)), 16), 
            Integer.toString(Math.round((255.0f/255.0f*255)), 16), 
            Integer.toString(Math.round((204.0f/255.0f*255)), 16));
```

I got the hexadecimal like this ff5394e4 . But i am getting very different color in  android  can anyone help me in this?.

IPhone Color:

[image]

Android Color

[image]

Comment: It shouldn't make much difference, but you forgot the "f" in the red conversion in the Java.

Comment: How different, can you add the images of the colors? There will be small differences due to the two devices having different display and different color capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that you need to round the converted values instead of just casting to an int.

For example, for a number `6.5`, rounding would get you `7`, but casting to an int gets you `6`. This may be the source of your problem.

I believe the java code to round a number is `Math.round(int)`.

Comment: In this case the smallest number would be from the calculation (0.329)*255 which truncated to 83 and rounds to 84 which minimally greater than a 1% difference.

Comment: Now that I see the colors I see how dramatic the difference is. I honestly do not know. I am sorry. I think there are some sites that list color conversions.

Comment: Wait, why are you doing /255 then *255? That would counteract itself.